# Why does c/_<CR> behave differently from cf_?

Tags: vim

Let's say I have the text `some_func` in my buffer and my cursor is on the `s`.

If I type `c/_<CR>` (where `<CR>` represents the [Enter] key), it removes the text `some` and enters insertion mode. If I type `cf_`, it removes the text `some_` and enters insertion mode. The difference is that `/` keeps the `_`, but `f` removes it.

However, `/_<CR>` and `f_` both behave identically (both move the cursor to the underscore), so why do they work differently for the `c` command? Is there a way I can configure Vim to make them consistent?

Comment: The traditional notation for `⏎` is `<CR>`.

Comment: @romainl thanks, updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:help /` says:

> Search forward for the [count]'th occurrence of
> {pattern} **|exclusive|**.

and `:help f` says:

> To [count]'th occurrence of {char} to the right.  The
> cursor is placed on {char} **|inclusive|**.

Pressing `<C-]>` with the cursor on either `|exclusive]` or `|inclusive|` leads to `:help exclusive`, which says:

> A character motion is either inclusive or exclusive.  When **inclusive**, the
> start and end position of the motion are included in the operation.  When
> **exclusive**, the last character towards the end of the buffer is not included.

Note that this only concerns motions used after an operator, `c` in this case, not standalone motions used for moving the cursor around. Check out `:help operator` for a more in-depth look at how operators and motions interact.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I especially appreciate the details on how to access help (I've never used :help, and also the Ctrl+] shortcut is helpful).

Comment: @KerrickStaley you won't get far in Vim if you don't learn how to use it's fantastic built-in help and make it a point of using it as first resort. Step 1: `$ vimtutor`. Step 2: `:help user-manual`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `c/_⏎` will change up to the next `_` even if the next `_` is on a different line, while `cf_` will do nothing if there is no `_` for the rest of the line. It seems like this is just a quirk of `/` when used as a motion; in this context, it just works more like `t` than `f`.